# diagnosing systemd boot messages

Tags: systemd

`systemd[989]: Failed to start XFCE notifications service.`

I've been trying to take first steps in understanding how to diagnose an error like the above. What/where is '989' and how do I find what/where the above error message is originating?  There are a million documents on the internet but none that I've found explains this.  Where should I start reading?

Here's another example:

```
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
smartd[516]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 77 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

... it's always 77 sectors, if I knew where the error was originating I might be able to suppress repetitive messages like that.

Comment: `989` is the pid, it originates from `systemd`. The second error is from `smartd`.

Comment: Ok, that's a start, it's the pid, but still, how do I trace these things back to source?  Of course the second is 'smartd' but the same principal applies -- how do I find where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

1. First message: [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), which is presumably used as `init`, is reporting that it could not start a service. Use

   ```
   sudo systemctl status xfce4-notifyd
   ```

   to find out why, or any logs provided by `xfce4-notifyd`. This is not an error message, this is the conclusion. If there were any error messages, they were before this message.
2. Second message: [`smartd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/smartd.8.html), the daemon which "monitors  the  Self-Monitoring,  Analysis  and Reporting  Technology  (SMART)  system  built  into  most  ATA/SATA and SCSI/SAS hard drives and solid-state drives", is reporting that your hard disk `/dev/sdb` has 77 sectors pending reallocation. *This is bad news*.

   To obtain a full report of the SMART data for that disk use

   ```
   sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
   ```

   If it was me, I would back up all the data from `/dev/sdb` and recycle the disk. A healthy hard disk will normally reallocate bad sectors internally; if it reports an error to the operating system it usually means that the disk is on its last legs.

Generally, syslog/journal messages look like this:

```
<timestamp> <host> <utility>[<pid>]: <message>
```

Messages from early stages of booting lack a PID for obvious reasons.

The utility can be a system-supplied program or a locally-developed one. If needed, try to use the documentation of the utility in question to find out what the message means, or the support forums for the utility.

Comment: sudo systemctl status xfce4-notifyd

Comment: "sudo systemctl status xfce4-notifyd" ... but that presumes that I know that the message in the log has something to do with 'xfce4-notifyd'.  What if I don't know that?  I'm not looking for advice on 'smartd', I'm looking for some way to always be able to link a message in the log to the program that generated it even without specific knowledge.  I dunno, maybe it can't be done.

Comment: @rayandrews: The name of the program or utility which generated the message is written in the message, after the timestamp and host name. In the case of the examples, `systemd` and `smartd`, as written in the messages. The message says that it could not start a service. Look in the service definition files to see which service is called `XFCE Notifications`. You will find it is `xfce4-notifyd.service`.

Comment: Closer ... where are the 'service definition files'? If I see a single actual example I'm sure I'll get the idea. For example you know that the message 'Failed to start XFCE notifications service.' is linked to the program 'xfce4-notifyd.service' ... HOW do you know it?

Comment: The message _itself_ includes the name of the program which generated it: `systemd`. If you don't know what `systemd` is, use [`man systemd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/systemd.1.html). The man page explains how to determine the directory in which unit files are kept. Go to that directory and `grep` for `"XFCE notifications"`; open the file in which it appears.

Comment: Things is, I was hoping for something more elegant than greping for strings, I'd do that anyway I though there might be a proper way to do it.